# NativeScript Oauth Plugin for Facebook - Can't Load URL

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-login, nativescript

I'm trying to use the nativescript-oauth Plugin to do basic facebook login in an app, as described here: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/introducing-the-nativescript-oauth-plugin. When I use the app ID/secret in the demo it functions correctly, but when I try to use my own I get the error that says ["Can't Load Url"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Bj2.png). There's definitely something wrong with my facebook app setup, but not sure what.

Is there a good guide to setting a facebook app up for an iOS app using NativeScript or another hybrid language? I tried using the quickstart guide on the facebook site but that didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

put localhost as your app domain in your facebook developer settings